# Is there an app for iOS which can extend Reminders with tags?

Tags: reminders

Something like that Fantastical can add to iCloud calendar, but for Reminders. My goal is to be able to use Siri to create reminders but then tag them up with extra metadata later on.

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.